# Error 401 in root site browsing from internet

Tags: error, authentication

I have a SharePoint site and from inside the server I can see the root site and the central administration. But if I try to browse the page from internet the server accepts my credentials and redirects me to the homepage but then I got a 401 error, any idea?

Comment: what authentication method used for the web site? how you enter your credentials i.e domain\users or ?try with different browser? again if you have to see if loopback check disabled

Comment: I use active directory, I hadn't touched the loopback check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I added myself in the user policy of the root web 80 and it works.